# How to properly have nested views to display?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-routing

So currently were working on a project which has many nested routes which must display. The reason being is were having two separate components displaying at the same which will switch out when clicked on. My question is how do we properly get a nested view to dynamically display?

To give you an idea of our hierarchy we have:
VIEW
|
HOME
|
CARD - Here is where we wish to display the various cards, I’ve gotten everything to display up to this point.

Here’s our current code for the files with code we tried in order to display:

HTML-----------------

```
<ion-grid style="background-color: red;">
     
        <ion-router-outlet name="view1"></ion-router-outlet>
        <ion-router-outlet name="view2"></ion-router-outlet>
    </ion-grid>
```

CARD.PAGE.ROUTING.MODULE--------------

```
{
path: ‘card-page’,
component: CardPage,
children: [
{
path: ‘view1’,
outlet: ‘view1’,
loadChildren: () => import(’…/view1/view1.module’).then(m => m.View1PageModule)
},
{
path: ‘view2’,
outlet: ‘view2’,
loadChildren: () => import(’…/view2/view2.module’).then(m => m.View2PageModule)
}
```

I appreciate any help or hints, please let me know if you wish for me to expand on anything, Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you explain what 'The reason being is were having two separate components displaying at the same which will switch out when clicked on. ' mean??

Comment: Hi! Apologies for the late reply but sure thing!  So what I wish to accomplish is to have two different components which are the nested children of the parent component display when the application loads both components will serve two separate functions. One works as a view and the other works as a button list which will change to another component depending on what is pressed.